# Problem populating dynamically created array

Tags: c++, oop, class

In the code below, I am trying to use a `for` loop to initialise the member `Name` of five objects of the class `book` using names taken from the string array `Array` (numbers in this case for testing purposes).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class book
{
private:
    string Name;
public:
    book();
    book(string&);
};

book :: book()
{}

book :: book(string& temp)
{
    Name = temp;
}

int main()
{
    string Array[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
    book *BookList = new book[5];
    for (int count = 0; count < 5; count ++)
    {
        BookList[count] = new book(Array[count]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, whenever I try to compile the code, I get the following error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:28: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘*(BookList + ((unsigned int)(((unsigned int)count) * 4u))) = (operator new(4u), (<statement>, ((book*)<anonymous>)))’
main.cpp:6: note: candidates are: book& book::operator=(const book&)
```

My intention is to create an array of objects using private member values that will only be known once the loop collects the relevant data. I'm following the advice offered in [answer #2 to a question I asked here previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267570/can-you-create-objects-using-variables-in-c/4267718#4267718).

Comment: It seems that you are making a `BookList` array and trying to initialize it with `book` objects.

Comment: You have to write a seperate setter method to intialize the member variable `Name`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
book *BookList = new book[5];
```

`BookList` is an array of five `book` objects.

```
BookList[count] = new book(Array[count]);
```

You are trying to use `BookList` as if it were an array of five pointers to `book` objects.

`BookList[count]` is not a pointer to the `count`th `book`, it *is* the `count`th `book`.

Have you considered using one of the Standard Library containers, like `std::vector`?

```
std::vector<book> BookList(5);
```

or, if you don't want to insert `book`s until you know what they are, you can create it with an initial size of `0` (by removing the `(5)` initializer) and `push_back` or `insert` books as you need to.

Answer (score 0):

```
BookList[count] = new book(Array[count]);
```

You are essentially doing:  `book  =  book*`  which will obviously not work, since they are different types.  You can drop the `new` keyword:

```
BookList[count] = book(Array[count]);
```

This will create a temporary `book` object, and assign it to one of the books in BookList.